# Achieve the same output without using multiplication ( * ) and division ( / ) operator

Tags: language-agnostic, operators

Suppose there is an statement like:

```
 variable output = (7 * X )/8  //[Here X will be provided by the user]
 //say for example , X=8
 variable output = (7 * 8 )/8 = 7
```

Now, I have to get the value of output variable `without using multiplication (*) and division (/) operator.`

Any suggestion or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the value 758?  where x=5

Comment: Is this an interview question or homework?

Answer (score 1):

You can use add and minus in *for* loops

ie: 7*X would equate to

```
int o = 0;
for( int n = 1; n <= 7; n++ )
  o += X;
```

and do something similar for dividing

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
int y = x>>3;
int ans = x-y;
```

Comment: Right shift by 3 bits will give the value of `(1/8)x`. `x-1/8x` will give `(7/8)x`